# Android dialog custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-dialog

On my screen I have an image view with a small image. I want the user to see the full size image when he clicks on it. So I thought I'd make a cancelable dialog with custom layout, which will have only the ImageView. So I created this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_product_full"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_full_product_image"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is even though I have every dimensions marked as `"wrap_content"` I still see some gap between the image and the dialog borders. I tried to set `padding:"0dp"`, set minHeight and minWidth to 0dp, but no avail, I still see that gap.
So how can I get rid of this gap? How can I make the dialog borders be adjacent to the image borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_product_full"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:contentDescription="@string/desc_full_product_image"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

The **fitXY** / **adjustViewBounds** Attribute should fix this problem.

Comment: android:adjustViewBounds="true" would be my next guess